# Parse Json error: required property expects a value but got null

Tags: airflow, power-automate

Hey can someone help me with this,

This flow has been working okay but I tried using it today, but I got this error. kindly help me figure it out. attached is my error and the prior steps and the schema

```
{
 "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "link": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "type": {},
            "size": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "referenceId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "driveId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "uploadSessionUrl": {}
        },
        "required": [
            "name",
            "link",
            "id",
            "type",
            "size",
            "referenceId",
            "driveId",
            "status",
            "uploadSessionUrl"
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

I have tried changing the dynamic input, but I still get other errors stating that the items cannot be found. Here is the step prior. I have also tried to create a variable called ‘Test’ or anything else that makes it easy to identify. Then I set that variable to the body/r053… then when I run the flow I can see what content is going into that variable before the flow fails.

I have tried looking at some solved solutions online, but I still got nothing substantial to solve this.

Comment: Can you show the schema to the `Parse JSON` step in its entirety?  Paste it into your question.  I believe I'll have an answer for you but want to check something first.

Comment: Hmmmmmm, just realised something, that expression looks very dynamic, i.e. the `body/r05348a7...` expression in the `Content` field of the `Parse JSON` step.  I suspect your body is changing after you make a major change to the form or something?  Can you check the JSON that comes back and compare it with your expression to ensure it's still lining up?

Comment: I have not changed anything in the slow/form. i changed the accounts it was under though. but it was working last week. also I cannot tell the output coz it considers the content field as a null.

Comment: So put something in between to see the output from the get form details call.  It's imperative to solving your problem.  You should also be able to see the output from that step as that's the input to the parse json step.